# Converting to Hex returns strange error

Tags: .net, vb.net, hex

The following simple expression raises `ArgumentOutOfRange` on my end:

```
100.ToString("X4")
```

I have tried replacing `100` with other constant values and integer variables, and have got the same result. I have changed `X4` to `X6` and simply `X` as well, again getting the same exception. The error message is:

```
Enum value was out of legal range.
```

Has anyone seen this before, or am I missing something really simple?

### EDIT

Here's a complete small program that reproduces it on my end (A Console Win application, add reference to System.Drawing):

```
Imports System.drawing

Module Module1
  Sub Main()
    Dim x As New ColorRange()
    Console.Write(x.ToString())
    Console.Read()
  End Sub

  Class ColorRange
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
      Return 100.ToString("X") & " - " & 100.ToString("X")
    End Function
  End Class
End Module
```

### EDIT 2

It looks like the error (bug?) is in the debugger. The value prints fine at runtime. Thanks to Jon. This is VS2010 Ultimate SP1 + Win 7 (64-bit) if anyone is interested.

Comment: Works for me... could you provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem?

Comment: @JonSkeet: Thanks Jon. Added an example.

Comment: That's not an example of using `100.ToString("X4")` though, is it? Your code gives me an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` in `string.Remove`...

Comment: @JonSkeet: Sorry, I was looking at it from my situation, where I tried to simplify `mMinColor.ToArgb()` with a simple integer `100` to get the error I mentioned above. I placed a breakpoint on that line and used Quick Watch window to evaluate `100.ToString("X4")` and got that error.

Comment: It sounds like this is a bug in Quick Watch then, rather than VB.NET itself. Please try to reproduce without needing the debugger...

Comment: @JonSkeet: Thanks a bunch. I am able to confirm that this error is in the debugger. The value prints fine at runtime, but Quick Watch and Watch windows raise the above exception. I was able to reproduce it with the very tidy code posted above.